# [Error Msg] The root link_base has an inertia specified in the URDF, but KDL

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys.
since I put the inertia value into the base link I got all the time the following error:

> The root link base_link has an inertia
> specified in the URDF, but KDL does
> not support a root link with an
> inertia.  As a workaround, you can add
> an extra dummy link to your URDF.

Now. I would create another link as suggested by the message, BUT in that case I must define a joint.
Since the base_link can move on 6DOF and the joint "floating" has been deprecated and not usable, I dont know how which constrains shoudl I use for the joint.

Any idea on how to get rid of the message?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192817/%5Berror-msg%5D-the-root-link_base-has-an-inertia-specified-in-the-urdf,-but-kdl-.../) by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 893 on 2014-09-16

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [filipposanfilippo](https://answers.ros.org/users/21802/filipposanfilippo/) on 2016-04-19**:
I am having the same issue. Could you please post or better explain your solution?

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2016-04-19**:
Create a frame 'odom' and a frame 'base_link' or whatever you like. Then joint them toghether with a fixed joint. The inertia must be put on the child frame, in this case 'base_link' otherwise you get the error.

**Comment by [filipposanfilippo](https://answers.ros.org/users/21802/filipposanfilippo/) on 2016-04-19**:
This is the message that I get when running roslaunch rrbot_control rrbot_control.launch:

The root link link1 has an inertia specified in the URDF, but KDL does not support a root link with an inertia.  As a workaround, you can add an extra dummy link to your URDF.

Any ideas?

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2016-04-19**:
After link1 create a dummy frame which has mass and inertia properties. You fix them together. You move the inertia from link1 to link_dummy

**Comment by [filipposanfilippo](https://answers.ros.org/users/21802/filipposanfilippo/) on 2016-04-20**:
Thank you, Andromeda! I have done the suggested modification. However, now my link1 has got a gray color (the one set is orange). How can I fix this? Also in the robot tree, linl1 is not appearing (it only shows link_dummy, link2, ...). Is this normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Would using a `fixed` joint with `[0 0 0 0 0 0]` (xyz, rpy) not work?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-09-17**:
No,
I already tried it.
Putting "fixed" it will literally fix the robot to the root link. No movement are possible. "floating" would be the right choice but it has been deprecated and is not usable

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-09-17**:
I think you're assuming the 'dummy link' should be the parent of `base_link`. I'm not sure whether that is actually a requirement? If you make your dummy a child with a fixed joint, wouldn't that work?

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-09-17**:
You are a genius.
Now I ve got it...
Thanks!

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-09-17**:
But in that case I must move the inertia into the child frame.
Will ROS it taking into account? And will move the parent _link accordingly?
I hope you can understand me.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

#### This is a simple example

---

Originally posted by [Amin.A](https://answers.ros.org/users/37509/amin.a/) with karma: 141 on 2018-09-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 14

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spkadam](https://answers.ros.org/users/44549/spkadam/) on 2019-10-18**:
worked for me.

**Comment by [trashperson](https://answers.ros.org/users/50716/trashperson/) on 2020-01-16**:
Thank you, you're a saver!!